# Create read only folder in C language

Tags: c, linux

I am using C language and Linux OS as my programming platform. And I want to know how can I make a read-only folder programmatically? Is there any mkdir command in C language for Linux or Unix-like system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do it is to use `mkdir(2)` to create the folder, populate it with the files you want it to have, use `stat(2)` to get the current permissions, mask out the write bits, then use `chmod(2)` to set the permissions.

Comment: Also what's wrong with the POSIX manpages for all the functions listed? There's no OS specific stuff required here.

Comment: If you set the mode explicitly within the `mkdir()` call then you can skip the `stat()` call, but then you end up ignoring the user's umask setting. Creating the directory read-only in the first place makes it so that you cannot later populate it. And yes, you can find each of those calls in section 3p as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the [**mkdir**](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_282.html) system call:

```
int mkdir (const char *filename, mode_t mode);
```

To make the newly created folder RO (no write and no execute permission) you can make use of the `mode` parameter as described [here](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_288.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int mkdir(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mkdir()` function

Synopsis:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

int mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode);
```

For example to create a folder named 'hello' that is accessible only by the current user:

```
mkdir("hello", 0700); /*the second argument is the permission mask*/
```

For further info type on the terminal

```
man 2 mkdir
```

If you feel creative you can do this in a more naive way

```
system("mkdir hello");
system("chmod 700 hello");
```

but there's no reason to do that...

Answer (score 0):

umask should work

```
#include <stat.h>
```